# Java Program debug - find smallest integer in the file

Tags: java

Below is the program, I couldn't find the error, can someone help? Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Proj2b {
     public static void main(String[] args){
         int i=0;
         int[] intArray = new int[100];
         try
         {   Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
           while(s.hasNextInt()){
               intArray[i++] = s.nextInt();
           }
           int small= intArray[0];  
           for(int j=0;j<intArray.length;j++) {
                   if(intArray[j]<small)
                     small=intArray[j];
            }
           System.out.println(small);
          }
         catch(IOException e)
          { System.out.println(e);
          }
     }
}
```

data.txt.
219 67 3
12 35 34 86 29
8 30
312 22 91 51 73
10 21
88
6

Comment: Logic error, compile error or runtime error?

Comment: What he wants is the smallest number in the input file to print. But it's actually printing `0`.

Comment: yep, unless there are 100 numbers in the file or you have negative numbers you'll always get 0

Answer (score 2):

Well you are initializing an array to be a fixed size 100:

```
int[] intArray = new int[100];
```

The `intArray.length` value will be 100, so you are checking a bunch of uninitialized values in your for loop.  Without running this, I assume they will be 0.  Can you give us more info about what is printing out in the System.out.println statement?

To fix this, I think you can replace this line:

```
for(int j=0;j<intArray.length;j++) {
```

with this:

```
for(int j=0;j<i;j++) {
```

since the variable `i` will hold how many integers were read in from the file.

Comment: Assuming you want 3 to print out, the above code change makes that happen, because as he stated, the array after item 19 is 0's.

Comment: @DavidFleeman Thanks David, it works now. So what is the best way to initialize an unknown size array?

Comment: I think your code is fine for the initialization if you know there will always be 100 or fewer numbers in the file.  I was just pointing out that they were uninitialized and that you were looping through them...  Glad it worked!

Comment: Right. Got it. I always make mistakes here and there :/. Thanks for help again!

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming the reason why you're getting that error is because the file data.txt is not in your class path. "data.txt" should be in your project's base directory, not in any of the directories that NetBeans has created for you but it could also be the size of your array

Comment: If it's executed from the same directory in which the input file exists, it will load properly. The core of this problem is due to the array being initialized to a size greater than the amount of data being read.